# Incorrect email address in account recovery mail

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email, account-recovery

I have an email address `"_eax_@mail.ru"`, but when I try to recover my account I receive mail with incorrect address:

> Someone requested an account recovery on Stack Overflow for eax@mail.ru, but we don’t have an account on this site that matches this email address.

Looks like the underscores are being ignored.

Comment: Did you sign up to Stack Overflow using a different email address?

Comment: can you give a link to your _original_ profile on stackoverflow?

Comment: When I have clicked "click here to recover your account" link I really do not had an account.I have registered later (right after receiving notification).

Comment: m0sa, my [profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/241751/hovsep)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, I have only one profile created via Facebook

Comment: @Hovsep: can you not login using Facebook? If not, you'll need to reset your Facebook account first, before being able to access Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: Can you explain,please, how it is related to issue?
The main issue is in underscore char in my email. My email address is "_eax_@mail.ru", but in notification i see 'eax@mail.ru'.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from the question, since the underscores transform the word in _italic_, in your question body `_eax_@mail.ru` appears like _eax_ @mail.ru

Comment: @DamienPirsy: I have edited question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your email address was picked up as markdown. Fix will be out in next build (rev `2013.11.18.1655` on meta and `2013.11.18.1160` on sites)